# Есть ли разница в вызовах ивента без отписки и с отпиской?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Разрабатываю оверлей для одной игры. Оверлей специфичный, не такие какие есть. Отображение урона нанесенного членами группы боссам, и еще немного полезной информации.

Возник такой вопрос, есть ли разница между вызовами событий у подписчиков событий в таком виде:

```
/// <summary>
///     Sends debug messages to the client.
/// </summary>
public event DebugMessage Message;

protected virtual void OnMessage(DebugMessageEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Message?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
}
```

И такого рода с удалением подписчика, если ссылка на него была удалена, но он остался подписан:

```
/// <summary>
///     Sends debug messages to the client.
/// </summary>
public event DebugMessage Message;

protected virtual void OnMessage(DebugMessageEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (Message == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Delegate[] eventListeners = Message.GetInvocationList();
    DebugMessage subscriber = null;

    foreach (Delegate eventListener in eventListeners)
    {
        try
        {
            subscriber = (DebugMessage)eventListener;
            subscriber.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
        catch
        {
            Message -= subscriber;
        }
    }
}
```

Есть ли разница между такими вызовами и нужно ли вообще так делать?

Comment: если исключение будет в самом обработчике ты от него отпишешься?

Comment: Да, т.к. код работает на стороне сервера, а в нем в свою очередь не должно быть исключений. Дабы он не упал.

Comment: странная логика.

Comment: Разница есть как минимум с потокобезопасностью. Ну и логике с отпиской не место в инвокаторе

Comment: @tym32167: Но как тогда обезопасить сервер от падения в случае исключительной ситуации, как только отписаться от него и не вызывать больше?

Comment: Я бы специальный класс тогда накатал для вызова, чтобы этот класс вызывал клиентов и заботился о логике, о кого отписаться, а от кого нет.

Comment: @tym32167: Не подскажите, атрибуты сериализуются? Подумал вешать атрибут автоотписки от клиента, если необходимо.

Comment: Ну это от сериализатора зависит, но, насколько я знаю, стандартными не сериализуются

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но разве убитый подписчик сам не отписывается при своей смерти? На сколько мне известно, руками управлять отпиской/подпиской имеет смысл тогда, когда объекты долго живут.